# ValidationException with Spring boot and Jetty

Tags: spring-boot

I set up a spring boot application(1.4.0.RELEASE) with the following configuration

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

As expected, this ran with embedded Tomcat. I then thought of trying the same with a Jetty server and followed the steps mentioned in the documentation here:
[Using Jetty instead of Tomcat](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat)

Basically excluding Tomcat and adding dependency for Jetty.Running mvn clean install from the command line or running the main method resulted in the following exception:

> Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to
>   load 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL
>   dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator
>   instead

I could solve this by adding the following dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not directly using any validation related code but I suspect this is getting pulled from the spring boot jpa starter which pulls in Hibernate. I have also seen a discussion around this here: [Similar issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2293)

Questions:

1) Is this the right fix?

2) If it is the right fix, should the documentation be updated to add this dependency as well?

Comment: I've just ran an empty `Spring-Boot` app with your `pom.xml` configurations and it's running as expected. Did you run a `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` when you changed stuff in your `pom.xml`? If you did and it produces the same exception, I think it would be worth adding the `<exclusion>` tag as per the Jetty Documentation that you stated above, without the `javax.el` dependency. Should you get the same error again, then your assumption might be correct to raise it to be added to the documentation or as a bug perhaps. But for me it works fine without the `javax.el` dependency.

Comment: The pom.xml above is the one which runs with the embedded Tomcat, that runs without the javax.el depedency. When I changed the pom.xml file to exclude the starter for Tomcat and include the spring-boot-starter-jetty dependency, I get that error. The error is thrown for both mvn clean install and for mvn clean package.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using the `javax.el` dependency. When the JPA pulls in Hibernate as you stated, it will use the Hibernate Validator. It's specified [here](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/). This is the right fix. As for the documentation, I personally would raise it but I suspect not everyone will have the same issue. I still can run my `mvn clean install` without errors however if I run `mvn spring-boot:run` it starts up and shuts-down straight after.